# Issue in step2exchange in google oauth for authorized G Suite marketplace app

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

We have an authorized G Suite marketplace app. We're trying to add another scope only in specific cases. For that matter, we've added the flag: `include_granted_scopes=true`. In the login process we are requesting the basic scope, with this flag, for the users who have additional scopes. However, only for users with **authorized G Suite marketplace** (the admin approved for installation and requests calendar related scopes), while performing `step2exchange`, we are receiving the error response:

> FlowExchangeError: admin_policy_enforced Access denied by a security policy established by the Google Apps administrator of your organization. Please contact your administrator for further assistance.

Requesting the same scopes without the `include_granted_scopes` works alright, as well as `include_granted_scopes` for all other users.